# JPA config with multiple repository implementation for a single repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have a scenario where i need to have 2 different implementation of a single repository (only one repository will be active at a time) based on Database from which that repository implementation is getting the data.

Example: 
`GroupRepository extends CrudRepository <String,Group>{} 
GroupSybaseRepository extends GroupRepository <String,Group>{}
GroupDB2Repository extends GroupRepository <String,Group>{}`

The solution that i am planning to have these repository implementation in different packages and using includeFilters/excludeFilters with

Any other better approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spring profiles.

Have two profile names `db2` and `sysbase` and Mark your repository accordingly with `@Profile` annotation.

While running the application specify which profile you want to be active using `spring.profiles.active` system property.

You can find an example [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles)

Comment: But aren't Spring Profiles provide a way to segregate parts of your application configuration and make it be available only in certain environments? Here environment is same for both the implementation.

Comment: The way I see it, DB on which the application is running is a distinct environment in itself and only one will be active at anytime. Which one is active we specify using active.profile. I think you are looking at env from dev, qa, prod etc. That is just another common example of spring profiles and once you start defining environment in your context you can use profile beyond example scenarios like dev, qa etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use two Repositories in the separate location, but you can achieve this by multiple ways( may be :-) )

But One could be:-

Using different Transaction Managers Like Below:-

```
@Repository()
@Transactional(value = "syBaseTransactionManager")
public interface GroupSybaseRepository extends GroupRepository <String,Group>{

}

@Repository()
@Transactional(value = "db2TransactionManager")
public interface GroupDB2Repository extends GroupRepository <String,Group>{

}
```

Now here you will be having multiple Transaction Managers in your context obviously. Thanks.

And you can have Conditional repositories also for the same. May be different configuration( classes marked with @Configuration marked with @Conditional based on some environment variable) files for both packages and transaction Manager Beans and other related beans also

Comment: Same location is possible? i mean without limiting the bean presence through configuration is it possible ?

Comment: Sorry to ask again but i think u must be referring to spring jpa entity manager not transaction manager.

Comment: Two transaction managers then two entity managers also, and two data sources also, and may be any other bean

Comment: you want to use 2 dbs together? or some other way?

Comment: No its never together as i mentioned in post... either of one is going to be used at a time. I can see my solution is working fine only issue is that i need to manually comment/ un-comment the code

Comment: Sure i am going to close this as a answer

Answer (score 0):

I used a combination of include/exclude filters the only bad part was that i have to comment/un-comment the specific filter definition when need to switch between repositories implementation. Something like below

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.concretepage">
 <context:include-filter type="regex" expression="com.concretepage.*.*Util"/>
 <context:exclude-filter type="assignable" expression="com.concretepage.service.IUserService"/>             
</context:component-scan>
```